# Convert time in string to datetime.datetime

Tags: firebase, time, timestamp, momentjs, strptime

I have a time in the form `time = '2022-06-29 07:55:28'` that has the type `str` I want to store it in the firebase in the firebase's format. For that I have tried `datetime.strptime(time, '%Y %m %d %I:%M:%S%p')`. But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2022-06-29 07:55:28' does not match format '%Y %m %d %I:%M:%S%p'
```

Kindly help me out in this. Should I go for momentjs or something similar?

Comment: looks like you're using Python, not JS?

Comment: Thank for suggesting, But I resolved the problem and posted an answer for it as well

Comment: uh yes, but if you had found the linked question first, would you have asked yours in  the first place? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was entering the wrong format. It should have been

```
time = datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

**Note: We have to enter the format according to the format of the data given!**